# Selecting first non null value and creating column label based on selection

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to find the first non null value from the utm_source column, for each anonymous_id and create a new column named first and label it with the value of the first non null value.

I asked a somewhat similar question previously and then figured out that I could get the first non null value using .first(). However I am having troubles assigning this value to a new column.

Here is my code:

```
first_two = pd.DataFrame(file[file['steps'] == 'Sign-ups'].sort_values(by=['ts']).groupby(['anonymous_id','year']).transform(lambda x: x['first'] == x['utm_source'].first()))
```

When I try and run this I get the following error message:

> KeyError: ('first', 'occurred at index Unnamed: 0')

This is a sample of the data I am using:

```
 {'steps': {0: 'Sign-ups',
  1: nan,
  2: nan,
  3: nan,
  4: nan,
  5: nan,
  6: nan,
  7: nan,
  8: nan,
  9: nan},
 'utm_source': {0: nan,
  1: 'facebook',
  2: 'facebook',
  3: nan,
  4: nan,
  5: nan,
  6: nan,
  7: nan,
  8: nan,
  9: nan},
 'ts': {0: Timestamp('2018-04-11 06:59:20.206000'),
  1: Timestamp('2019-05-18 05:59:11.874000'),
  2: Timestamp('2018-09-10 18:19:25.260000'),
  3: Timestamp('2017-10-11 08:20:18.092000'),
  4: Timestamp('2017-10-11 08:20:31.466000'),
  5: Timestamp('2017-10-11 08:20:37.345000'),
  6: Timestamp('2017-10-11 08:21:01.322000'),
  7: Timestamp('2017-10-11 08:21:14.145000'),
  8: Timestamp('2017-10-11 08:23:47.526000'),
  9: Timestamp('2019-06-12 10:42:50.401000')},
 'anonymous_id': {0: '0000f8ea-3aa6-4423-9247-1d9580d378e1',
  1: '00015d49-2cd8-41b1-bbe7-6aedbefdb098',
  2: '0002226e-26a4-4f55-9578-2eff2999de7e',
  3: '00022b83-240e-4ef9-aaad-ac84064bb902',
  4: '00022b83-240e-4ef9-aaad-ac84064bb902',
  5: '00022b83-240e-4ef9-aaad-ac84064bb902',
  6: '00022b83-240e-4ef9-aaad-ac84064bb902',
  7: '00022b83-240e-4ef9-aaad-ac84064bb902',
  8: '00022b83-240e-4ef9-aaad-ac84064bb902',
  9: '0002ed69-4aff-434d-a626-fc9b20ef1b02'},
 'year': {0: 2018,
  1: 2019,
  2: 2018,
  3: 2017,
  4: 2017,
  5: 2017,
  6: 2017,
  7: 2017,
  8: 2017,
  9: 2019}}
```

Note: I converted my dataframe to a dictionary just so its easy for everyone to see and interact with the data

An example of my expected output would be

```
anonymous_id      utm_source          first             year
  1111              Facebook         Facebook           2017
  1234                NaN              NaN              2017 
  1243              Google           Google             2018
```

To reiterate the column 'first' would be labelled based on the first non_null value found in utm_source (the first ad the anonymous_id clicked)

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: @MichaelD added that to my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, we can use `groupby` with [`first_valid_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.first_valid_index.html):

```
df.loc[df.groupby('anonymous_id')['utm_source'].apply(lambda x: x.first_valid_index())]\
  .dropna(subset=['utm_source'])
```

**Output**

```
    steps utm_source                      ts                          anonymous_id    year
1.0   NaN   facebook 2019-05-18 05:59:11.874  00015d49-2cd8-41b1-bbe7-6aedbefdb098  2019.0
2.0   NaN   facebook 2018-09-10 18:19:25.260  0002226e-26a4-4f55-9578-2eff2999de7e  2018.0
```